# I receive the PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: when moving a file using shutil.move is there any way to ignore this error?

Tags: python, error-handling, shutil

I have python code that moves a folder and the images within to another location. i'm doing this using shutil.move. Sometimes it will error out and I get the PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied: is there any way i can ignore this error and have it so the script continues with the next item.

Comment: Handle the error with a `try` / `except` block?

Comment: what would this look like ?

Comment: ```
try:
    <code that creates error>
except:
    pass;
```

Comment: You might want to go through the Python tutorial. Specifically [this chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).